# Website with a lot of animate gifs runs high CPU

Tags: cpu-usage, animated-gif

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem. I have a site much like http://giphy.com, that runs a lot of animated gifs. The site currently runs a high cpu of 40-50%. I need to find I solution to lower the CPU usage without having to remove images because the images are chosen by the users. The site can have between 20 to 30 little animated gifts at a time. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: This CPU you speak of, it's server side or client side?

Comment: Only show the animated GIF version when the cursor is over the image.

Comment: Client side browser cpu, trying to help converse battery power for mobile and laptop users.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can combine all gifs inside a single file and display it at one. you're out of luck

Comment: You know actually I tried that, I did a side by side comparison of a few images on a page which show a that the page with the combined did have a lower CPU but once the number of images increased they still consumed about the same amount of CPU. Also a lot of the images are user generated and uploaded, making that impossible to match up frame and combined.